# Update model instance with dynamic field names

Tags: python, django

What I want to do is pretty simple:

```
f=Foobar.objects.get(id=1)
foo='somefield'
bar='somevalue'
f.foo=bar
f.save()
```

This doesn't work as it tries to update the f object's 'foo' field, which of course doesn't exist. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
f = Foobar.objects.get(id=1)
foo = 'somefield'
bar = 'somevalue'
setattr(f, foo, bar) # f.foo=bar
f.save()
```

> [`setattr`] is the counterpart of `getattr()`. The arguments are an object, a string and an arbitrary value. The string may name an existing attribute or a new attribute. The function assigns the value to the attribute, provided the object allows it.