# Update a field of a Django Object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to update an object field in django. Usually I would do something like this:

```py
# MODEL ---
class MyObj(models.model):
    name: models.CharField(max_length=10)
    surname: models.CharField(max_length=10)

# VIEW ---
# [...]
   myObj = MyObj.objects.get(pk=1)
   myObj.name = 'John'
   myObj.save()
```

The problem is that the field to modify (in the example above: "name") is not known and passed as an argument to the `post` request. So I would have something like this:

```py
# VIEW ---
# [...]
   field = self.request.query_params['field_to_modify']

   myObj = MyObj.objects.get(pk=1)
   myObj[field] = 'John'
   myObj.save()
```

now this triggers the error:

```
myObj[field] = 'John'
TypeError: 'MyObj' object does not support item assignment
```

What is the correct way to update an "unknown" field of a django object?

### UPDATE

Thank you for your answers so far! OK so the way to go is apparently using `setattr` (as per the answers). Now the problem is that it does not allow me to save the modified object without checking if it is valid.

So I tried using the Serializer to check the object validity but is not working:

```py
field = self.request.query_params['field_to_modify']
myObj = MyObj.objects.get(pk=1)
setattr(myObj, field, 'John')
serial = MyObjSerializer(myObj)
serial.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
serial.save()
```

error:

```
AssertionError: Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#setattr) to set an attribute by name.

```
field = self.request.query_params['field_to_modify']
# TODO: add validation for `field`
myObj = MyObj.objects.get(pk=1)
setattr(myObj, field, 'John')
myObj.save(update_fields=[field])  # no need to update anything but the single field
```

Of course, this won't let you automatically attach any arbitrary data to models and expect it to be saved; if you need something like that, maybe use a JSON field.

## EDIT:

For using a Django REST Framework serializer (which, cough, wasn't part of the original question or tags, but could be inferred from `query_params`), one could do

```
field = self.request.query_params['field_to_modify']
myObj = MyObj.objects.get(pk=1)
serial = MyObjSerializer(instance=myObj, data={field: 'John'})
serial.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
serial.save()
```

Comment: Can I validate the whole object using its serializer after `setattr`? like `serializer = MyObjSerializer(myObj)` and then `serializer.is_valid()`?

Comment: can you expand your answer on the validation issue? (see update) Thanks.

Comment: Sure. See my edit. Your original post didn't mention DRF at all though.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it looks like Django model instances do not support that operation.  It looks like you can use setattr though from looking at this previous question / answer.  [Update model instance with dynamic field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937661/update-model-instance-with-dynamic-field-names)

Comment: Hi there, I've tried `setattr` but I'm having validation issues, can you check the updates to the answer and expand your answer? Thanks :)